# I am using spring hibernate application with oracle database. i get an error org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException

Tags: spring, oracle, hibernate

I am using spring hibernate application with oracle database.
 I am getting an exception

```
 HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection.
```

During this time I cannot access database from the server using netbeans or any other tools .
But I can ping with the server.
So many people got same error and but they do not get any proper way to resolve this problem.

Comment: 07-May-2015 16:29:11.822 WARN [http-nio-8083-exec-16] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions SQL Error: 12519, SQLState: 66000
07-May-2015 16:29:11.823 ERROR [http-nio-8083-exec-16] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12519, TNS:no appropriate service handler found

Comment: Your application is not able to open the connection with Database. Can yuo check if you have rights to access the same.

Answer (score 0):

Your server is not able to connect to database, check the setup on how you declared db configuration, jdbcm user, pwd and driver. Something is wrong in the setup configuration in server for which it is refusing connection.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like your Oracle Names resolution (TNS) ist not working correctly . check your oracle client installation. try to tnsping the db service from command line to see wether its reachable...

check SQLNET.ORA and  if you are using local naming TNSNAMES.ORA file

Comment: Actually I'm getting the connection and i can work with that but sometimes i got this error.